# C# Could not load file or assembly Interop.InetCtlsObjects

Tags: c#

I've upgraded a VB6 project to C# and I'm trying to run a winforms project and I have the `Interop.InetCtlsObjects.dll` file in my project and I've added a reference to it, but when I'm trying to run it I'm getting this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly
'Interop.InetCtlsObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But I can see the file and I added a reference to it's exect location...
So what am I missing here ???

Comment: A quick google said this is for "Internet Transfer Control", since you are converting to C# anyway are you sure there isn't a better C# alternative you can use instead for your task?

Comment: have you registered the com dll on the machine?

Comment: Do you know a better alternative ?

Comment: I don't know what you are using it for so I have no idea, try looking on google for "c# myTaskIAmTryingToComplete"

Comment: @LiranFriedman HttpClient, WebClient, or even the "low-level" HttpWebRequest or FtpWebRequest. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well since this is not  my project, I received it for conversion from VB6 to C#, I have no idea what it is supposed to do... Do you think trying to register the dll on the machine could work ?

Comment: @LiranFriedman I don't think that you can convert a project if you don't know what it does. You'll *definitely* waste a lot of time if you try to use the ... somewhat quirky ... ITC in a C# project

Comment: Best idea is to go through it one line at a time and TRY and determine what you think it's supposed to do.  Map it out (use a sheet of paper and a pencil if you have to) and then try and reconstruct the logic using more modern constructs.

Comment: I think there will be no easy way to do it but this...

Answer (score 0):

Delete the reference, save the project and add it in again. It is possible that you are somehow referencing a different version and the compiler cannot find the right DLL because of it. If that doesn't work, check your app.config and make sure the versions for this particular DLL match.

Comment: @LiranFriedman All desktop application can have an `app.config` file, which include settings, assembly redirections etc. Are you confusing it with `web.config`?

Comment: No, but by default winforms does not have an `app.config` file so I didn't think it must have it

Comment: @LiranFriedman only the most trivial applications have no settings